# Jython executing SQL query against Oracle takes too long (comparing to Python)

Tags: python, sql, oracle, jython

I have a Jython script that runs (execute join query against Oracle database) much slower than very similar Python script (same SQL query and same Oracle DB).

This is Jython:

```
from com.ziclix.python.sql import zxJDBC
connect = zxJDBC.connect("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//ip:1521/ORCL", "user", "pass", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
cursor = connect.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Python:

```
import cx_Oracle
ip = 'ip address'
port = 1521
SID = 'ORCL'
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, port, SID)
connection = cx_Oracle.connect('user', 'pass', dsn_tns)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
```

SQL query has joins and filters but exact same SQL query runs with both Python and Jython and Jython seems to be 10x slower executing it.

How to make Jython have the same speed as Python while executing SQL against Oracle?

For example - running a Python code that joins 3 tables with 100K records (after join and filtering) takes 3min to execute (and less than 1min to fetch all records).
Same SQL using Jython takes 30min (or more) to execute and longer to fetch as well.

Comment: Provide and define your elapsed-time measurements.  Are you counting the JVM warm-up time when measuring Jython's performance?

Comment: Added. How much can be accounted to JVM warm-up ?

Comment: Include the data fetch time in the test too, since one may be prefetching data and the other not - along with other variances.  It's really how fast you get the data back that matters.